# Editing css in a settings page for a web based program on Android

Tags: java, jquery, android, css, xml

I have created an application for the Android that displays HTML pages through `WebView`. Each page uses one communal CSS page.

What I am attempting to do is create a settings page that will allow me to alter the CSS which would consequently result in a change in all the HTML pages. I have looked everywhere for a way to do this and have of yet been unsuccessful in my search.

Comment: you need a server side language to open the file and write the results.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what your referring to. Can you please clarify?

Comment: You need to pass the `data that needs to be changed` to the server, we would do that through something like ajax. You would use JAVA (I see you tagged it) to `parse the data being sent`. Then you can use JAVA to open the file and write these parameters. Please see this tutorial -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bypass writing an Android preferences activity, and keep all the smarts in the web app, simply encapsulating this in a webview, your best option is to use a server-side language for I/O access, as others have suggested above. Since you're using JavaScript already, why not keep everything JS? node.js seems like as good a solution as any to me.

You'll want to check out the node.js API doco [here](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). What you want is:

```
fs.write(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, [callback])
```

fd refers to the filename and location, and you'll need to specify buffer, offset, length, and position to tell node where in the file you want to write.